# How to convert D&D 2e campaign to 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, adnd-2e, conversion

Much of my original campaign is 2e D&D, but am now starting up again with 5e.
What are your best tips to convert adventures and the campaign world to 5e?
The creatures and classes all translate, but what about details (e.g. 2e had all sorts of sub-classes)?

Comment: This is pretty broad and discussion-ey, so I imagine it'll end up being closed. I suggest spinning this into multiple, focused questions. Like "how do I implement my 2e gladiator (Compleat Fighter's...) in 5e?" and the like. There's no stigma on multiple, good questions here!

Comment: @nitsua60 Don't we already have a Q&A on this?  I believe that these two questions are very close, if not dupes. [1](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/47205/22566) and [2](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/85023/22566)